# Select and sort data from one table on certain columns

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I'm looking to see if it is possible to select data from table A with a sort so the order of the data changes.

I then want to make a loop so it will go through each row and add it into table B.

Is this possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable `@row_number` to store the incremented num for your expected sorting.

```
SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, Column1
FROM TableA
ORDER BY Column1
```

This result can be store in temporary table and based on that you can do loop/insert into the TableB